# How can I delay a css animation until the element is visible?

Tags: css

I have this animation that makes a h1 and p "fly in":

```
@-moz-keyframes titledrop {
                0% {
                    -moz-transform: translateY(-80px);
                }
                100% {
                    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
                }
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes titledrop {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: translateY(-80px);
                }
                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
                }
            }
            @keyframes titledrop {
                0% {
                    transform: translateY(-80px);
                }
                100% {
                    transform: translateY(0);
                }
            }
            @-moz-keyframes drop2 {
                0% {
                    -moz-transform: translateY(-80px);
                }
                100% {
                    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
                }
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes drop2 {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: translateY(-80px);
                }
                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
                }
            }
            @keyframes drop2 {
                0% {
                    transform: translateY(-80px);
                }
                100% {
                    transform: translateY(0);
                }
            }
```

But sometimes the animation starts before the element is visible, so it looks like nothing happened. How can I delay a css animation until the element is visible?

Comment: Are you saying your element has visibility:hidden set on it that is removed? Or do you mean delaying the CSS animation until the page is loaded?

Comment: what do you mean by "visible"? Do you mean once the element enters the `viewport` (aka scrolling?)

Comment: I mean when the page has loaded and the element is visible.

Comment: Listen for doc ready or the onload event with JavaScript and then apply a class that will start the animation.